# How to use common class for AlertDialog in Android Application

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want to use AlertDialog in every screen of my Android Application so I want to make a common class "Activity_AlertDialog" in my project which will contain code for AlertDialog. I'll call this class wherever I'll need a dialog in my project.
But how do I call positive and negative buttons from this common class?
My sample code:

```
package com.example.AlertDialog;



public class Activity_AlertDialog extends android.app.AlertDialog {

Context context;
String title, msg, negBtn, posBtn;

public Activity_AlertDialog(final Context context, String title, String   
message,
        String negBtn, String posBtn) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    this.msg = message;
    this.title = title;
    this.negBtn = negBtn;
    this.posBtn = posBtn;

    Activity_AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new     
Activity_AlertDialog.Builder(context);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle(title);

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage(msg);

    // Setting Icon to Dialog
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ttt_logo);

    // Setting OK Button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton(posBtn,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Write your code here to execute after dialog closed
                    Toast.makeText(context, "You clicked on OK",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton(negBtn,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "You clicked on No",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }
            });

}
}

Function in my Application where I'm calling this class:

@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {


        case Utility.MENU_LOGOUT:
            Activity_AlertDialog dialog = new 
Activity_AlertDialog(Activity_Search.this, "Alert Dialog",
                    "You have an unsaved Draft.\n"+"Do you want to save 
it?","No","Yes");
            // How to call positive and negative buttons from Activity_AlertDialog class here?????

            return true;


        default:
            return ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use

> dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).performClick();

to call positive button of the dialog and use AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE to trigger the negative button of the dialog.